# jq Conditional output

Tags: json, command-line, jq

I'm using [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to play with json. I was wondering how to conditionally print something in that.

Say I am interested in a field call `geo`. I used the following command and find out there is only one entry whose `geo` is `null`:

```
% cat all.json | jq '.geo != null' | sort | uniq -c              
   1 false
6891 true
```

How can I print out that entry only without printing everything else?

Didn't see something like `print` command in the manual. And this doesn't work: `cat all.json | jq 'if .place == null then . end'`. `jq` complained about syntax error.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

You can use the [select](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)) function to get only required entries:

```
jq 'select(.geo != null)' all.json
```

Comment: The select works, but to fully answer the question you'll need to filter only the geo again, piping inside jq: `cat all.json | jq 'select(.geo != null) | .geo' > geo-only.json`

Comment: Just a reminder that the `cat` is unnecessary, you could do `jq 'select(.geo != null) | .geo' all.json > geo-only.json`